# Wordpress ajax url ... not send

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I have a javascript file that is trying to send POST data to a php file that is in a directory above it in my filesystem:

```
plugin 
|js
 /script.js
|saveData.php
```

script.js:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: '/../saveData.php',
    data: {
        obj 
    }, //send data if needed
    success:function(){
        alert("OK sent data!");
    }
```

This however, doesn't seem to work. How should I be referencing this file? I am also a little bit confused as to where this php file should reside to begin - I need to be able to make calls to the $wpdb class. Any help/advice appreciated!

Comment: is your script output by a plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Ajax in WP, you can't use your url, you have to use `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )`. See more in this link: [how to use WordPress Ajax](http://ducdoan.com/working-with-wordpress-ajax/).

Comment: Ended up using get_admin_url. I'm new to wordpress, so didn't even know about this method until you mentioned it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The URL needs to be relative to the HTML document the JS is running inside, not to the JS file itself.

If it did need to be relative to the JS file then you would want `../saveData.php`. Starting with a `/` goes back to the root of the webserver (and then the `../` tries to go up a level from there, which is impossible, so that bit is ignored).